# Graphics show up as unknown on a Dell Inspiron 1564

Tags: 11.10, compiz, 64-bit, intel-graphics, inspiron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my Intel integrated graphics to be recognized in System Info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

I have a Dell Inspiron 1564 i3 330M. I dual boot it with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Prior to installing Oneiric, I had the 32 bit version of Natty installed. Everything used to work fine. However, with the release of Oneiric, I decided to install the 64-bit version, but so far, my experience has been VERY bad.

It refuses to recognize the integrated Intel HD graphics. In System Info, in the Graphics section, it says that the drivers are unknown and the experience is standard. In Natty, however, it correctly gave my graphics as Intel HD Graphics.So how do I get the OS to recognize my Intel HD graphics? I have all the latest updates.

Comment: Can you split these up into separate questoins? This site works best when there's one post per question

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Installing mesa-utils will allow the graphics card to be recognized as an Intel Ironlake Mobile, but your experience will stay standard. I have not yet figured out how to get the full compiz experience with this graphics card.