# How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Lenovo IdeaPad y510.

System info says

```
Graphics: unknown.  
Driver: unknown,  
Experience: Standard.
```

What should I do to use all my laptop hardware components to work properly with Ubuntu?
Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 69):

it means that it cannot acquire the information because glxinfo is not installed on the system.

Install it by clicking here:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

This is bug [914631](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa-demos/+bug/914631).

After installing mesa-util it's providing information about graphic. In my case (Probook 4530s) "Intel® Sandybridge Mobile", while experience index still the same: Standard.

Answer (score 23):

Install Mesa-Utils by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Then it will be detected.

Comment: +1 this is a know bug.  The card is detected by the system but not shown on the GUI.  As stated in the answer installing `mesa-uitls` will get the card to show.  You may also want to see my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/154877/65969) on installing the texture compression libs that will allow you to play the newer games that require s3tc support.

Comment: Thank you for answer, after I install mesa-uitls the system can get the card to show and I will have a look.

Answer (score 11):

For Ubuntu to show the correct information in the details window, You should install the package `mesa-utils`.

Open a terminal and execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Comment: and this is not installed by default, why?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same graphics device and the "Unknown Driver" problem. This is not a problem with the driver installation but with the fact that Ubuntu is unable to recognize it properly.

If you can see a properly functioning GUI and not a black and white Command-line screen, then your Graphics Card is working fine.

This issue has been frequently discussed:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1949097

If the graphics performance appears to be poor it may be simply because Precise does'nt have wobbly windows and other special effects enabled by default (or at least not in low end systems). Download Compiz and enable these effects and animations. They should work fine with Intel GMA Integrated Graphics (they do on mine!).

Comment: To be able to recognize it install `mesa-utils` , compiz IS already install in 12.04 as Unity IS a compiz plug in, what it's not installed is the settings manager, effects like the wobbly windows are not enabled by default on the installation.

Comment: Unity may be a Compiz plugin but I don't think Compiz Settings Manager is installed by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes that's what i said.

Comment: Get th latest Kernel, the Intel drivers are in the Kernel

Comment: @UriHerrera, please add your comment in a question, i worked

Comment: In a question? I don't undertsand..?

Comment: @UriHerrera, oh, it was a typo. I mean answer. Your answer worked.

Comment: @UriHerrera Your comment worked for Anwar. Please add your comment as an answer so he can accept it. Thanks.