# Do I need to install a driver for a Mobile Intel® 4 Series Express Chipset Family video?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

I'm currently running 2 os on my laptop (HP Compaq 420), win 7 ultimate and ubuntu. Im just wonderin what is the right graphic driver for Mobile Intel® 4 Series Express Chipset Family. Im asking this because after i install ubuntu (with internet connection), it seems like theres no graphic driver installed .

When i look at the system info it labels "Unknown" next to the graphic word .

Answer (score 1):

The information you see in the *System Information* is unreliable (it can also happen with other graphic adapters) the Intel drivers are installed as part of the setup and need no further packages to work by default.

If you really what to see what card is in use and the driver used for that card open a terminal and type `lshw -C display` and look for the `configuration: driver=<some_driver>` line.

Comment: So it means that all the drivers needed for the OS to work is already installed ? (Aside from graphics)

Comment: Including the Intel driver. Run the command in a terminal, you will see your card and the driver its currently using, no need for anything else.