# Ubuntu does not recognize my nVidia GPU driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I installed the driver from Additional drivers I can run nVidia configuration utility which recognises the GPU but when I go to system info it says

Driver : Unknown
Experience : Standard

Also when I move windows around the desktop they move slowly or they will only move to final position when I stop moving the mouse also CPU usage rises significantly when moving a window (by 50% on 1st core and 40% on second)

Comment: You should provide more information about your problem. What is your nVidia card model? It has Optimus technology? (If you dont know, post the output of the following command: `lspci | grep VGA`)

Comment: give it time .... mine laptop has a Intel HD 2000 and even after installing it took upto 3 days go show Iron Clarke thingy

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get my Intel integrated graphics to be recognized in System Info](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is recognizing your Nvidia video card driver otherwise it would not be able to activate it and you would not be able to have a 3D desktop.

It is System Info that is not recognizing the video card. It is my guess that this is because the Nvidia driver is proprietary code and not open source code.

I get the same information from System Info on my machine with Nvidia Geforce GT220. Accept this as the present situation regarding proprietary video drivers.

Last night I ran a test on a default install of 12.04 Beta 1. I deactivated the Nvidia driver and I re-booted. I got a 2D desktop running under the open source video driver called Nouveau.

In 12.04 System Info is called Details. The details of my graphic set up under Nouveau are:

> Graphics: VESA:GT216 Board-0682vb12
>
> Driver: 0682vb12 Experience:
>
> Standard

Notice, that the graphic experience is listed as standard. This means 2D. In 12.04 you can confirm this by running System Settings>Appearence. If you see a method of adjusting the Launcher icon size, then you are in 3D. You do not get (at present) a method to adjust the Launcher icon size in 2D.

When I re-activate the Nvidia driver, Details (System Info) says:

> Graphics: Unknown
>
> Driver: Unknown
>
> Experience: standard

The experience is standard even though I know I am in 3D mode. I can see the effects. Therefore I conclude that System Info at present cannot get information from a proprietary video driver because it is closed source code.

For your information, the video card that you have is a key component for having a good visual experience in any operating system.

You do not give us your hardware specifications. Does your video card have a powerful GPU (Graphic Processing Unit)? How much video memory is on the card itself? This can make all the difference to a user's visual experience.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, found by adding this repo and updating my NVidia drivers worked for me: http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-install-nvidia-2750907-driver-in.html

Comment: Plus try: Compiz-Setting-Manager.... Composite: AUTO DETECT REFRESH (UNTICK): REFRESH RATE SLIDER (MAX)..... MOUSE POLLING: (1)