# Graphics driver details is not shown in my system inf

Tags: 11.10

I have a Dell Latitude D630 system, No graphics driver data is available in system info window. Do i need to install graphic driver? if yes how to do it? 
I'm a very beginner to Linux and Ubuntu.

Dinesh.

Comment: Not necessarily. I am using 11.10 and 12.04 alpha and my System Info also says Graphics - Unknown and Driver - Unknown, Experience - Standard. This part of the utility will work if we are using the Open Source driver. But it does not yet recognise the capabilities of proprietary drivers. At least not the Nvidia ones I am using. Follow the suggestion in the first answer.

Comment: please see:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info

That worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

Try opening up the additional drivers program, and see if there is anything available. From a quick Google search, I found out that your laptop has Nvidia, so this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that it says unknown for most intel cards as well. And when it does show something its like "Mesa/Driver" or w/e. I really wish it would just say what the actual graphics card is. an example would be

Prcessor- i7 quad core 3.0ghz (4 Logical)
Graphics- Intel mobile 4 series chipset (64MB Video Memory)

That would be very useful in my book.