# Ubuntu 11.10 won't detect drivers for Intel HD Graphics 3000

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my Intel integrated graphics to be recognized in System Info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

From what I read, Ubuntu 11.10 should just pick up and install the drivers. But it's not, under the graphics section of system info it just says "Driver Unknown".

Any Ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to install anything with that GPU. Is this a dual-GPU/Optimus system by any chance?