# Can't get my graphics driver (GMA 3150) to work

Tags: intel-graphics

I've been searching like crazy trying to find a fix for this, it's the only thing that's not completely working on my setup. I see posts where people say it should be working but it just isn't.  I have a Gateway LT2802u netbook and I installed 11.10 on this 2 days ago. Everything works except for accelerated graphics. At first I couldn't watch a simple flash video at all, but somehow I got it to work. Now the last problem I have is I can't watch HD videos, my screen resolution won't go higher than 1024x600, and my under my graphics driver it says "Unknown".

After doing as much research as possible, I've come to the conclusion that it's the GMA 3150 graphics driver. There is a bunch of talk on it all over the interwebs but nothing lately. I've tried the fixes that some people have used but most when I try to get the package it's no longer there or available if that makes sense. I'm loving everything Ubuntu has to offer but it'll really bite if I can't use it any more because of this problem. Does anybody have any ideas? You'd really be helping a lot.

Comment: The graphics being listed as "unknown" is highly likely to be http://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info .  Do you expect the netbook to have a resolution higher than 1024x600?  What I've found on the web suggests that your netbook *has* a 1024x600 display, so that's correct.  Given these two things, are  there still remaining problems?

Comment: I could've sworn it was a little higher on windows.  But now that I've researched it, it looks like that part is right.  I guess the last part would be I still can't run simple HD videos on youtube and it still says unknown for my graphics.

Comment: So, as mentioned on that other question, ‘unknown’ will almost certainly be fixed by installing `mesa-utils`.  What, precisely, do you mean by “can't run HD videos on youtube”?

Comment: Any quality video higher than 480 runs like a slideshow in 5 second intervals.  And I already have that installed and it still says unknown.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you GMA 3150 is working correctly.

Playing HD content ( even 720p ) is usually not possible with such hardware as the video decoding cannot be handled by the GMA 3150 hardware on any OS including windows .

Just confirm that you can view 480p youtube video in HTML5 mode http://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: 720p works with me. im using s10 3t lenovo , 2 gb ram , 1.66 atom, 3150 gma. win7 32bit. No lag when watching 720p.

Answer (score 1):

Your GMA 3150 can handle HD videos up to 720p. But not through flash. Adobe flash is using CPU to accelerate video playing - and forcing GPU encoding doesn't work for me with this GPU. But if you download the reguested video first and then play it in Gnome Mplayer (With enabled gpu acceleration) it will work without problems. Or try Minitube.

Answer (score 0):

install intel graphic drive:

Open terminal and type

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
sudo service lightdm start
```

Go to setting --> display and uncheck mirror and click detect display

1. select laptop and turn off
2. select your monitor and change screen resolution you want
3. click apply and keep this configuration, then you are done.