# Unrecognized video card "Intel HD Graphics"... help?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my Intel integrated graphics to be recognized in System Info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

I installed the new version of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS .
Download and install the 32 bit (it automatically installed the PAE kernel) I notice the problem arises when small accents and I'll see the "Details" the system tells me "graphics: unknown" and tried to find anything but neither Jockey my video card is "Intel HD Graphics" and my machine is a Lenovo G460L with Intel Core i3 Micro and 4GB of RAM. As I can solve the problem? I need to use 64-bit?

Image of Problem: [image]

Thanks, Yours sincerely Juan Pablo Lozano