# Graphics experience?

Tags: graphics

**Hi there.** 
I Have a question about a option in system preferences.

If i go in Details and select *Graphics*, i can find tis 2 options:

1. Driver (mine is GTX470/etc...)
2. Experience (mine is **standard**)

My question is, if there are other types of graphics experiences?
If yes, what types, and how i change it?

If no, what is the utility of this thing?

Thanks. :D

Comment: Mine is **standard** too but I can play Minecraft with 120 Frames per second and this is good. I don't know exactly if there are any other values possible.

Answer (score 4):

The graphic experience is how you will experience the desktop environment

If you're on standard it means that you can run Unity 3D on your computer

It used to be a different changeable option before 10.10(?). It had 3 modes determining the amount of effects used in Compiz

Related: [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)