# What does "VESA: Madison" in the graphics driver information mean?

Tags: drivers, graphics

It indicate "Experience:standard" on graphics driver. What does it mean, is there any other experience other than standard? or can it be upgraded?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125657/graphics-experience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *Madison* is simply AMD/ATI's code name for the [Mobility Radeon  HD 56xx/57xx series GPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units) (laptop video cards):

  [image]
- This description indicates that you have one of these GPUs in your laptop, *and* that Ubuntu is successfully using the proprietary *fglrx* driver; no changes are necessary.
- "Standard" is the normal graphics experience, allowing the use of the Unity (3D) desktop; it's not possible to "upgrade" it.

Comment: Thank you for this information. And thank you for guiding me on how to ask question. Apology for my past questions and I will be very careful next time.

Comment: @obetus: You're welcome, very glad to see you more active on the site :)