# Intel Graphics Card not detected in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, graphics, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my Intel integrated graphics to be recognized in System Info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

I've Installed Ubuntu 12.04 64bin alongside Windows through Wubi. But this version is not using Intel display drivers. The graphics section in Details menu in System Settings shows drivers as 'Unknown' and Experience as Standard. Hence the overall experience in Ubuntu 12.04 is slow.

The output of `lspci | grep VGA` is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```