# Installing propriety Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, steam

I have a 2012 Alienware x51 and I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on it with the hdmi plugged into my Nvidia 660 graphics card. It installed the nouveau drivers by default and I have no option in the "additional drivers" section to install Nvidia driver so I installed it manually from the Nvidia web site but Steam complains that there is a OpenGL incompatibility.

Why is there no option to install Nvidia drivers in the "additional drivers" section?

All I want to do is have Nvidia drivers to test out Steam on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mybe look at this: 
[How to install a driver for an NVIDIA card not detected by Additional Drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129322/how-to-install-a-driver-for-an-nvidia-card-not-detected-by-additional-drivers)
[NVidia Doesn't Show Up in Additional Driver + Power Regression Issue in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126369/nvidia-doesnt-show-up-in-additional-driver-power-regression-issue-in-ubuntu-1)

> Know that The Nvidia card is not compatible with Unity 3D. The Intel HD 3000 is. That >means that if you're using Unity 3D now, it's the Intel card which is in use. And the >fact The Graphics Driver name does not appear in Systems Settings (Details),

also maybe helpful (external url)
http://linuxg.net/install-new-nvidia-drivers-nvidia-319-17-on-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/

I would remove all manually installed drivers, reboot and check if it appears then.
Maybe try running jockey-gtk as sudo "sudo jockey-gtk"

Last i checked the 310 experimental drivers where required for steam.

Comment: Another link ....
Blank "Additional Drivers" running a Nvidia 680GTX raring 13.04  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1173024