# Graphics coming as Unknown, I have Intel 4500mhd

Tags: intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

I have Acer Aspire 5738g and it has Intel GMA 4500MHD graphics. When I check System it shows the Graphics as: Unknown, Driver as Unknown.

How to install latest drivers in ubuntu for Intel 4500MHD ?

Thanks.