# Do I need additional graphics drivers win an Intel HD graphics 2000?

Tags: drivers

I use both Linux Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 on my Desktop which has Intel HD Graphics 2000.  Do I require additional drivers for the Linux operating system to use the HD graphics and if so, will these drivers effect how the windows OS operates?

Answer (score 6):

No, Intel Video drivers are provided out of the box with Ubuntu, there's no need to install additional drivers.

The system information dialog will not show the proper driver, see this question for more details:

- [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

Comment: And Unity 3D will work out-of-the-box with HD Graphics 2000 :)

Comment: it written in details section, graphic driver : Unknown
It needs to be known

Answer (score 2):

Video Drivers are Operating system specific. So whatever driver you install on Ubuntu has no effect on your Windows installation. And vice versa.

Now, you may not NEED additional drivers. Ubuntu may run smooth just as it is with the defaults. But if there are any available in the hardware driver manager. I'd say get them, as it will only improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu supports Intel HD 2000/3000 VGA cards without any driver installation. But it doesn't get listed in "System Settings>Details>Graphics". You should install mesa-utils to get it listed.

> sudo apt-get install mesa-utils