# Details window showing "unknown" driver for Graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, performance, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

I have Intel Graphics Card, which have model number GM965. It is on a Notebook, (Lenovo 3000 Y410).

My Ubuntu Installation worked good until I upgraded to 12.04. It was a fresh install. The  Graphics performance is poor compared to Natty, Oneiric. In the **details** tab of **System Settings**, Graphics driver is shown as "Unknown". I have upgraded the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package to version 2.19.. from 2.17. But still same.

So, My question is **Is there any other method to fix the problem with graphics showing as "unknown"**?