# Missing Graphics Card Driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Details window showing “unknown” driver for Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151608/details-window-showing-unknown-driver-for-graphics)

When I open "details" at dash home, I check what graphic driver my computer is using but it says unknown. Is this a bug or anything else?
What should I do?
I'am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: See possible duplicate questions: [How can I get my Intel integrated graphics to be recognized in System Info](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info) and [Details window showing “unknown” driver for Graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151608/details-window-showing-unknown-driver-for-graphics)

Answer (score 0):

Installing mesa utils should take care of that. In a terminal, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not missing if you have anything other than a text only screen, it is a harmless to leave it like that, your system has found it but the "details" windows does not find it.
You can verify it by typing into a terminal:

```
lspci | less
```

the second entry will be your graphic card.

If you want to have it identified you can install `mesa-utils` with

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

mesa-utils will also give you some diagnostic programs to check that your 3D render is working properly such as:   `glxdemo, glxgears, glxheads, glxinfo`