# Installing mesa-utils messes up video driver info

Tags: drivers, video, aspire-one, mesa

After I installed `mesa-utils` in order to get rid of the "Unknown Driver" message (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151608/details-window-showing-unknown-driver-for-graphics)) I got contradicting info about which driver is actually being used.

"System Settings" says: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300), but if I type `lsmod | grep video` I find `psb_gfx` in the "video" row.
Any idea?

Especially, if Gallium is really being used, how to remove it and fall back to `psb_gfx`?
I'm using an AspireOne 751h with Atom, so processing power is pretty scarce and I'd prefer not to waste it to run a SW emulation of a GPU.