# Details showing unknown driver for graphic

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, games

I have AMD Graphics Card, which have model number Radeon HD 8450G. It is on a Notebook, HP PROBOOK 445 G1

My Ubuntu Installation worked good . It was a fresh install.  In the details tab of System Settings, Graphics driver is shown as "Unknown".

Comment: Question has been answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/151608/details-window-showing-unknown-driver-for-graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glxinfo is not installed on the system. It seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa-demos/+bug/914631)

you need to install the package: mesa-utils

This package provides several basic GL utilities built by Mesa, including glxinfo and glxgears.

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

[source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/mesa-utils)