# Why do Intel HD3000 graphics show as "unknown" on my Lenovo B570?

Tags: graphics, intel, lenovo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

Well as it says in the question title, I'm running a Lenovo-B570, I have an Intel HD Graphics 3000 integrated card, and inside the graphics thing it says Unknown, and Standard experience, I have tried doing other things I have seen on AskUbuntu but, once I get other drivers to show up, it starts to get choppy, and a lot of my drivers stop working, not to mention my sidebar icons and such go invisible... And even then Second Life wouldn't work and kept saying that I don't meet the required specs and such. Could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`apt-get remove mesa-utils`

Reboot and verify that the problem persists, if so:

`apt-get install mesa-utils`

Reboot and verify if the problem is solved.

I've tried this solution many times, i also have an intel card, and it works

Comment: I believe that's the command that I entered into Term that gave me all of those other drivers that didn't do anything for me but make the display choppy and permanently deactivate my Wifi abilities, and that made all of my icons invisible

Comment: That's weird because usually is what people do to get the Unknown issue fixed. That's also what i do in my laptop and it works. Do you only have an intel graphic card, or do you have another graphic card also?

Comment: It's just the Intel HD Graphics 3000, no other, and I did that Mesa thing, it made my graphics card show up, but Second Life still says that my laptop doesn't meet minimal graphical standards or something, but it did when I had Windows 7

Comment: @TishonHeart you may need S3TC support libraries. See my answer about that [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/154877/65969) Some games will still not work as they still don’t see the s3tc support(Psyconauts was one, it may be fixed now...). Also the `mesa-utils` worked for me with my Sandy-Bridge Intel...

Comment: @Trailrider Is that the sudo command that gives all of those updates and gives the drivers like Acer Extras and Intel KVC and stuff like that (Guessing at the names I forget what they are actually called)

Comment: not sure what you are asking here.  `sudo` is needed to install any software.  If you are asking about the answer given by LynxSlck above, that command only installs `mesa-utils` if you are talking about the command in the answer I gave for S3TC, it only installs the needed library for S3TC compression. (libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0).  Using `sudo` is not some magic command that installs every available program, it is the command you use to get super user privileges to access root(system) owned files. `apt-get` will only install the program YOU tell it to(+plus any required dependencies) and nothing else

Comment: The texture thing you told me to install didn't help at all, the graphics still aren't workig