# Why are Intel HD 3000 graphics (Sandy Bridge) detected as Unknown?

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my Intel integrated graphics to be recognized in System Info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

When I go into system information

When I check System it shows the Graphics as: Unknown

[image]