# graphics card not found?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my Intel integrated graphics to be recognized in System Info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

I just installed  Ubuntu 12.04 and absolutely love it , but when i go to system details
it says graphics unknown, is this a problem ? i have a acer aspire 5750, and a Intel 3000 HD graphics card.There also no additional drivers to be installed, but on another computer i needed to install additional drivers and it showed the grapics card. is there a problem with intel graphics in combination with ubuntu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot acquire the system info because `glxinfo` is not installed.

Install the package `mesa-utils` by clicking on the icon below:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or by opening a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

This is bug [914631](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa-demos/+bug/914631) on Launchpad.