# Why do System Detail doesn't show my graphics card

Tags: nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

I am using Nvidia 9500GT Graphics Card and so I use Nvidia Proprietory Driver as my Driver
[image]

But in the System Detail it shows Graphics Unknown why?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Install it & it will show you