# How do i install HP 620 laptop graphics driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, laptop, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

On the intel site there is no Mobile Intel GMA 4500MHD driver for linux.
They link this site though http://www.intellinuxgraphics.org/
claiming to develop such a driver. there are no ubuntu packages there or any file that I could install. can Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Intel graphic is open-source and integrated in your Ubuntu installation, so you should already have drivers installed.

Check `glxinfo`.