# Ubuntu 12.04 not recognizing the graphic card

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, gpu

I just installed an Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on my laptop which has this graphic card:

Nvidia Geforce 610M 2GB

but the output of `lspci | grep VGA` is this:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1058 (rev a1)
```

I've use another laptop like this and it should show the model of the GPU not controllers.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work) & also, you should get intel in system info. If systeminfo showing `unknown`, read [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

Comment: system info doesn't recognize the gpu, but instead of unknown it shows the intel controller of my cpu  wich is : Intel® Sandybridge Mobil. and i have installed mesa-utils

Comment: Yes it won't be recognized, because nvdia optimus isn't supported in linux by nvidia. The nvidia chip isn't directly connected to the laptop display. Instead, nvidia generated images are transported through intel card. Intel card is the one that drives your display. Read the first link for more info how to use nvidia card. Or you can google how optimus system works.